# Why can't PHP insert new geometry on PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, gdal, ogr, php

(Copied this question from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890338/why-cant-php-insert-new-geometry-on-postgis), since it may have more answers here.)

I'm using ogr2ogr to upload a GPX file to PostGIS.

When I do it on command line (Ubuntu 14.04), it works fine.

```
ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=... dbname=... user=... password=..." 2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml
```

When I do it on PHP (5.5.9),

```
exec("ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:\"host=".HOST." dbname=".DATABASE." user=".USER." password=".PASSWORD."\" /var/www/html/plantas/gps/2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml 2>&1",$output,$retval);
```

it gives the following error:

```
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)

Command: INSERT INTO "waypoints" ("wkb_geometry" , "ele", "time", "name", "cmt", "desc", "sym", "type", "gpxx_waypointextension", "wptx1_waypointextension", "ctx_creationtimeextension") VALUES ('010100000000008C76C2DF4EC00100C0A13A450E40'::GEOMETRY, 594, '2015/11/16 17:22:09+00', 'ROP_2904', '08-NOV-15 9:56:51
PONTO 60', '08-NOV-15 9:56:51
PONTO 60', 'Flag, Blue', 'user', ' SymbolAndName ', ' SymbolAndName ', ' 2015-11-16T17:22:09Z ') RETURNING "ogc_fid"
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer waypoints (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT

I tried Mike T suggestion:

```
$linha = "ogr2ogr -append -f PostgreSQL PG:\"host=".HOST." dbname=".DATABASE." user=".USER." password=".PASSWORD."\" -s_srs EPSG:4326 /var/www/html/plantas/gps/2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml 2>&1";
// or $linha = "ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:4326 -append -f PostgreSQL PG:\"host=".HOST." dbname=".DATABASE." user=".USER." password=".PASSWORD."\" /var/www/html/plantas/gps/2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml 2>&1";
exec($linha,$output,$retval);
```

to no avail:

```
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)
```

What's really strange is that exactly the same command works on terminal. So I think PHP might have some issue, perhaps a missing library or permission?

Comment: Is PHP able to read a file in that path? Maybe user rights are a problem.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Yes, PHP can read the file. Just did $texto = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/plantas/gps/2016-04-26_15-32-01.xml'); echo "[$texto]"; and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started it all again:

1. restored a previous database from backup;
2. `create extension postgis;`
3. `create extension postgis_topology;`
4. `ogr2ogr` from console creates additional tables (like `waypoints`);
5. after this I need to grant access in those additional tables to php/apache user.

Comment: Ah, the `SELECT` permissions were not granted for the role to see the SRS info from the `spatial_ref_sys` table. This would cause the odd "SRID (0)" error.